# Javascript set value of many elements is very slow

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

I have a loop that change value of input and I do not find any solution to optimize that because the loop take more than 5 secondes.

My loop look like this :

```
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    const element = document.getElementById(`txt-assembly-${i}`);
    element.value = "40";
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't really take 5 seconds or anywhere close to that time. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The only way I can see this taking that long is your computer is bogged down, or there are an exorbitant amount of elements. https://jsfiddle.net/xkjfqcv8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, setting `value` on 50 elements isn't slow, it's near instantanous. Your performance issues must be elsewhere. Try looking at the dev console performance tab in chrome.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(document.createElement('input'));

let reset = val => [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
  .forEach(el => el.value = val);
  
reset(40);
  
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => reset(Math.random() * 100));
```

```html
<button>random</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ok thank you, I have a layout forced reflow many time I think thats why, I will find why I have a reflow at each loop